# En SqlClient, sólo me aparecen SqlClient.SqlClientPermission y SqlClient.SqlClientPermissionAttribue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, conexión

soy programador de Visual Basic.Net. Hace cosa de cuatro años aprendí a conectar con el SQL Server y a utilizar bases de datos de SQL Server. Pero ahora estoy intentando hacer lo mismo, y cuando quiero hacer la conexión, no me deja.

Ya abrí el Explorador de Servidores desde el Visual Studio 2019 y lo conecté con una base de datos de SQL Server, ya tengo la cadena de conexión (el "DataSource" y todo eso, etc.). Pero ahora toca hacer lo siguiente:

```
Dim Conexion as SQLClient.SQLConnection
```

Pero no puedo... Después de escribir `SqlClient.`, entonces sale la lista desplegable de todas las clases disponibles para poner a continuación, y sólo me salen `.SqlClientPermission` y `.SqlClientPermissionAttribute`. ¿Dónde están todas las demás clases de `SqlClient.`?

El caso es que tengo un proyecto que hice hace cosa de cuatro años, en aquella época en que aprendí a usar el Sqlclient, y ahí sí me aparecen en la lista desplegable todas las clases de `SqlClient.`

Una cosa muy rara, vamos...

Estaría eternamente agradecido a quien pudiese echarme una mano.

Comment: Ya leíste la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/open-database-by-sql-server-dotnet-data-provider)?

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Arriel. El caso es que yo todo eso ya sabía usarlo, de hecho cuando abro un programa que yo hice hace cosa de 4 años, veo que en él funciona todo esto. Lo que ocurre ahora es eso, que con SqlClient, sólo me salen esas dos clases que pongo en el título del mensaje, mientras que en el proyecto que hice hace 4 años, lo abro y ahí en cambio sí que me salen todas las clases de SqlClient. Una cosa rarísima... ¿Tú imaginas qué puede ser?

Comment: `Imports System.Data.SqlClient Module Program Sub Main(args As String()) Dim cn = new SqlConnection()`. Cuando hago `cn.` me salen todos los objetos de los que hablas. Estoy utilizando VS2022, .NET 6.0, `System.Data.SqlClient` version `4.8.3`

Comment: Mira @Arriel, aquí tienes dos capturas de pantalla donde se puede visualizar el problema: https://ibb.co/8mJXfBK
https://ibb.co/YL4CM28

Comment: **Qué es lo que quieres lograr?** `SqlClient` es parte del namespace `System.Data`. No es parte de `System.Data.SqlClient`. Tu segundo error en la captura te dice que `SqlClient` no está definido. Tienes que importar el otro namespace...

Comment: @Arriel mira, he cambiado la llamada del Imports y me sigue pasando lo mismo: https://ibb.co/ctj0BjK
https://ibb.co/CmXymNs ¡

Comment: Ok. Vamos por partes. Cambiaste el texto o cambiaste **también** la referencia? Cuando haces click en las dependencias en el explorador de soluciones, te sale `System.Data` o `System.Data.SqlClient`? Si es el segundo, agrega el primero. Cuando te vas al archivo del proyecto, qué versión de `SqlClient` te sale?... Cuando haces hover en la línea roja del error, te sale alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Entiendo que quieres abrir una conexión. Probaste lo que te sugerí en mi segundo comentario? `Dim cn = new SqlConnection()`? Por qué insistes en utilizar la clase `SqlClient`?

Comment: [Aquí está el tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/open-database-by-sql-server-dotnet-data-provider#create-adonet-objects) para utilizar SqlClient en VB.Net. **En ningún lado** se abre la conexión de la manera en que tú lo quieres hacer.

Comment: Te agradezco la paciencia que estás teniendo, @Arriel. Échale un vistazo a este nuevo pantallazo. ¿Hay algo incorrecto por aquí? https://ibb.co/xf1rvkr

Comment: Creo que si cambias el import a `System.Data.SqlClient`, debería funcionar

Comment: Me parece que ahora lo he puesto bien, y sigue pasando lo mismo: https://ibb.co/BjMs8KM

Comment: Gracias por incluir el screenshot de las dependencias. No veo `System.Data.SqlClient` entre ellas. Veo `System.Data`, pero no `System.Data.Sql.Client`. https://ibb.co/W2zGmH1

Comment: Pues ahí está el tema... Debería aparecer, ¿no? Por eso te digo, que de las clases de SqlClient, en la lista desplegable que me sale al poner ```SqlClient.``` sólo me salen dos elementos, que son los que dije en el título de este tema, pero me deberían salir todos los demás, SlConnection incluido. Lo que me extraña es que me salgan los dos que me salen, porque uno piensa que lo normal es que o funcione bien y salgan todos, o no funcione y no salga ninguno. No sé... Una cosa más rara...

Comment: No es tan raro.... A veces, **escribir Imports no es suficiente**. Eso sólo es texto en la clase que estás escribiendo. Eso funciona con clases como System.Text, porque ya viene en las librerías básicas de un programa básico. SIN EMBARGO System.Data no viene como parte de las librerías básicas, entonces hay que agregar la dependencia. DA CLICK DERECHO a las dependencias y le das agregar referencia y buscas el SqlClient

Comment: Mira en el screenshot que te compartí. Ahí está la referencia al ensamblado SqlClient. Por favor intenta incluirlo en tus dependencias.

Comment: Nada, amigo... He hecho click con el botón derecho sobre "Dependencies", y en el menú contextual que me sale, arriba hay las siguientes opciones: "Add Project Reference", "Add Shared Project Reference", y "Add COM Reference". Y en ninguna de los tres encuentro nada relativo al SqlClient...

Comment: Lo solucioné, @Arriel

Answer (score 0):

Descubrí el error: cuando abres el Visual Studio 2019 y te pregunta qué quieres hacer, vas a "Create a new project", y ahí vas a buscar el tipo de proyecto. Hay una opción que es "Windows Forms App" a secas, y otra en la que te pone "Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)". Pues bien, la primera no vale, tienes que coger la segunda (la del .Net Framework).

Tú ves que pone "Windows Forms App", y lo seleccionas, ¿cómo vas a pensar que esa opción no es válida y que hay otra opción distinta que también se llama "Windows Forms App"? Pues vale, de casualidad lo acabo de descubrir, viendo que hay esas dos que tienen la designación muy parecida.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, @Arriel.